# DynamoDB Delete just replaces attributes with <empty> and keeps the primary key

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

When deleting an item from my dynamodb table via the Go SDK, I don't get an error or any issue.  The records attributes all get replaced with empty strings.  Instead of removing the record, the primary key stays in the table with empty attribute fields.

The crazy thing is, if I run the CLI version of the command, the entire line item goes away.  What am I doing wrong here?  Is there something specific to go and dynamodb that I'm missing?

This is the go code that replaces first_name and last_name with "" and preserves the primary key.

```golang
    input := &dynamodb.DeleteItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String("Consultant"),
        Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "consultant_id": {
                N: aws.String(strconv.Itoa(consultant.ConsultantID)),
            },
            "first_name": {
                S: aws.String(consultant.FirstName),
            },
            "last_name": {
                S: aws.String(consultant.LastName),
            },
        },
        ReturnValues: aws.String("ALL_OLD"),
    }

    _, err := client.DeleteItem(input)
    if err != nil {
        return serverError(err)
    }
```

This is the code that deletes the entire line item for partition keys equal to "7" (sample ID field)

```sh
aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name Consultant --key "{\"consultant_id\": { \"N\": \"7\" } }"
```

Comment: Why do you have first/last names in the key you've supplied?

Comment: just testing, we tried with just the partition key originally and added the other attributes to see if the issue would go away if we were more specific in our request.  the result is the same with or without non-keyed attributes, the key stays in the table and the non-key attributes are set to "<empty>" kind of like a tombstone record in Kafka or Cassandra

Comment: You never have to, and should not, supply more than the key attribute(s) when deleting an item. I don't use the Go SDK but your code, minus the extraneous first/last name, would seem to be valid. Any chance that you have another process modifying this DynamoDB table?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!  I'll be sure to remove as I saw examples of just the partition key or examples with attributes.

No other processes are modifying this table.  It lives in a POC environment that only a few people have access to.  we're building this via Extreme Programming so the only ones that have even touched this table or the code base are the driver and there coder.